# AssertionError in Flask App when connecting to database using config in blueprint

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-mysql

I am building a Flask application which connects to an existing MySQL database as an exercise to learn Flask. I am encountering an error when trying to connect to the database, from a database object which is instantiated from a blueprint.

My Project structure is as follows

project 
    ├─── instance 
        ├─── config.py
    ├─── application
        ├─── _src
            ├─── db.py
            ├─── extensions.py
        ├─── admin
            ├─── templates
            ├─── __init__.py
            ├─── views.py
    ├─── static
    __init__.py

My __init__.py (in the applications directory) has the following code:

```
from flask import Flask

# Config file
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.config.from_pyfile("config.py")

# Blueprints
from application.admin.views import adminBlueprint

# Register the blueprint
app.register_blueprint(adminBlueprint)
```

My Config file has the following:

```
#####################
# Database details ##
#####################
DB_USERNAME = "username"
DB_PASSWORD = "password"
DB_DATABASE_NAME = "databasename"
DB_HOST = "localhost"
```

The views file, in my admin folder has the following:

```
# Imports
from flask import render_template, Blueprint
from .._src.db import DB
from .._src import admin as admin

# Config
adminBlueprint = Blueprint("admin", __name__, template_folder="templates")

# Routes
@adminBlueprint.route("/admin")
def admin():
    # Connect to the database
    db = DB()
    cursor, conn = db.connectDB()
    # Get the required data
    projects = admin.getProjects(cursor, "all")
    # Close the database connection
    db.close()
    # Render data to the template
    return render_template("admin.html", projects=projects)
```

My extensions file, in the _src folder, which is used to allow access to the MySQL object from the blueprint, has the following code:

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
mysql = MySQL()
```

And my db file in the _src directory has the following:

```
from flask import current_app
from .._src.extensions import mysql

class DB:
    def __init__(self):
        # Something will be done here in the future
        pass

    def connectDB(self):
        # Provide the database connection details
        current_app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = current_app.config["DB_USERNAME"]
        current_app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = current_app.config["DB_PASSWORD"]
        current_app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = current_app.config["DB_DATABASE_NAME"]
        current_app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = current_app.config["DB_HOST"]
        mysql.init_app(current_app)
        # Connect to the database
        try:
            self.conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            # Return the cursor object
            return cursor, self.conn
        except:
            return False

    def close(self):
        self.conn.close()
```

I'm getting the following error:

> AssertionError: A setup function was called after the first request
>   was handled. This usually indicates a bug in the application where a
>   module was not imported and decorators or other functionality was
>   called too late. To fix this make sure to import all your view
>   modules, database models and everything related at a central place
>   before the application starts serving requests.

And the debugger is pointing to this file in the db file:

```
mysql.init_app(current_app)
```

I'm a little out of my depth and I don't really understand what the problem is. Can I only initialize the MySQL object from the same place that I initialize the Flask app? If so, how can I then access the MySQL object from the blueprint?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by putting my app instantiation into my extensions file instead of my init file:

**extensions.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.config.from_pyfile("config.py")
```

Then, in my database connection object, I can import the current app to get the settings:

```
from flask import current_app
from .._src.extensions import mysql
```

I also removed this line, as I am now achieving this in my extensions file:

```
mysql.init_app(current_app)
```